# Regex replace contents of file and delete lines that don't match

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a large log file where I want to extract certain types of lines. I have created a working regex to match these lines. How can I now use this regex to extract the lines and nothing else? I have tried

```
cat .\file | %{ 
    if($_ -match "..."){
        $_ -replace "...", '...'
    }
    else{

        $_ -replace ".*", ""
    }
}
```

Which almost works, but the lines that are not of interest still remain as blank lines (meaning the lines of interested are spaced VERY far apart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to remove the `else` clause altogether. If you do that, then no object will be returned from that iteration of the `ForEach-Object` block.

```powershell
cat .\file | %{ 
    if($_ -match "..."){
        $_ -replace "...", '...'
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the regex run once per line? if I add a `s` flag I don't think that would help? Either way, I'de prefer a solution that doesn't modify the regex

Comment: And this time I actually tested it!

Comment: Ohhhh I see. If I don't output anything it doesn't go into the next pipe - so if I don't output a blank line I wont get a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Just to append to [briantist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803314/3829407) you don't even need the loop structure. `-match` and `-replace` will function as array operators. Removing the need for the `if` and `ForEach-Object`.

```
(Get-Content .\file) -match "..." -replace "...","..."
```

`Get-Content` being the target of the alias `cat`

Comment: Very nice, +1! @David Grinberg, Powershell has a lot of things like this and they really come in handy. Note that some of them were added in Powershell 3 (like using `.Thing` on an array of objects that contain a `Thing` property, to return an array of Things), so also be aware of which version you're writing for.